# Is $i\sqrt[4]{10} \in \Bbb Q(\sqrt[4]{10})$ or is my proof wrong?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, extension-field, splitting-field

So I'm working on a question on splitting fields and I'm a little confused by the result I keep getting. Any help would be very much appreciated.

I have to construct the splitting field of $(x^4-10)(x^2-20)$ over $\Bbb Q$. We can factorise the given polynomial as

$$(x^4-10)(x^2-20)=(x-\sqrt[4]{10})(x+\sqrt[4]{10})(x-i\sqrt[4]{10})(x+i\sqrt[4]{10})(x-2\sqrt{5})(x+2\sqrt{5}).$$

So now we know the roots. Testing if $\sqrt[4]{10}$ is a an element of $\Bbb Q$ goes as follows:

Suppose it is. Then $\sqrt[4]{10}=\frac{a}{b}$ for some $a,b, \in \Bbb Q \Rightarrow a= \sqrt[4]{10}b$, a contradiction. So it is not an element of $\Bbb Q$.

The polynomial $x^4-10$ is irreducible by Eisenstein's Criterion with $p=5$. So we conclude that

$$\Bbb Q(\sqrt[4]{10}) \cong \Bbb Q[x]/\langle x^4-10\rangle. $$

and now we know that $\Bbb Q(\sqrt[4]{10}) := \{a+b\sqrt[4]{10}+c(\sqrt[4]{10})^2+d(\sqrt[4]{10})^3 \mid a,b,c,d \in \Bbb Q \}$.

This next part is where I feel I must be messing something up because it doesn't make sense to me. To see where the next extension will come from I tested to see if $i^4\sqrt{10}$ is an element of $\Bbb Q(\sqrt[4]{10})$.

I tried to aim for a contradiction. That is, suppose $i\sqrt[4]{10}=a+b(\sqrt[4]{10})+c(\sqrt[4]{10})^2+d(\sqrt[4]{10})^3$. Then

$$10=a^2+(2ab+20cd)(\sqrt[4]{10})+(2ac+b^2+10d^2)(\sqrt[4]{10})^2+(2ad+2bc)(\sqrt[4]{10})^3+20bd+10c^2 $$

Obviously we don't want any of the quartic roots involved so we want either $a=0, b=0, d=0,$ or $c=0, b=0, d=0$.

If we take the former option, however, we are left with $10=10c^2$. This implies that $c=\pm 1$, but this is not a contradiction. So does this mean that $i\sqrt[4]{10} \in \Bbb Q(\sqrt[4]{10})$? Or does it just mean that I can't use a proof by contradiction argument here?

Comment: $\Bbb Q(10^{1/4})\subseteq \Bbb R$, $i10^{1/4}\notin\Bbb R$.

Comment: $i\alpha\not\in \mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ for all real $\alpha$.

Comment: This is hard to read. What is $i.^4\sqrt{10}$? "i point power of 4 square root of 10"? If you want the fourth root of 10 you write that as `\sqrt[4]{10}`: $\sqrt[4]{10}$ If you want a multiplication symbol you can use `\cdot`. For ideals, use `\langle` and `\rangle` rather than `<` and `>`.

Comment: yes I felt intuitively my result was impossible. could anyone please elaborate on where I made my mistake

Comment: I have edited the question for clearer readability.

Comment: Where is $x^2-20$ coming from?

Comment: It's a bit better but there is a lot to be improved. Your title and each new paragraph should begin with a capital letter. The word "working" in the first line should not be capitalized. The end of every sentence needs a period (yes, even if it ends with mathematical symbols). The word "I" should always be capitalized. The apostrophe should be between the 'n' and 't' in "doesn't". If the mathematics appears on a line by itself then it should be in display mode (typeset with two dollar signs: `$$...$$`). There should not be a space before the question mark at the end.

Comment: @Chickenmancer I'm afraid I dont understand your question. It was arbitrarily chosen at the start ? It's just part of the random arbitrarily decided product of polynomials $(x^4-10)(x^2-20)$

Comment: @Trevor Gunn I edited it again!

Answer (score 2):

The key is that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{10})$ is not the splitting field of your polynomial, but it is a subfield of it. The reason is, as said in the comments, that $i\sqrt[4]{10}\notin \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{10})$, since $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{10})\subset\mathbb{R}$. Adding $i\sqrt[4]{10}$ as a generator gives you all the roots, so the splitting field is $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{10}, i\sqrt[4]{10})$.

Comment: Two questions. 1) what about the roots $+-2\sqrt{5}$ ? 2) I know how to construct the field extension $\Bbb Q(\sqrt[4]{10},i\sqrt[4]{10})$ but how could i show that the field extension is needed . i.e. that $i\sqrt[4]{10} \notin \Bbb Q(\sqrt[4]{10})$

Comment: 1) Use that $\sqrt[4]{10}=\sqrt[4]{2\cdot 5}$ to find an algebraic combination (sums and products) that gives you those roots.

Comment: 2)  $i\sqrt[4]{10}$ is a complex (imaginary) number. All numbers in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{10})$ are real.

Comment: okay cool, I had just wondered if it was enough to just state this or if we needed to prove it